# How to move mouse in MS Outlook via autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Which is the way to move the course to the cursor position in Microsoft Outlook (2013) using autohotkey?

The following is not working

```
MouseMove, % A_CaretX, % A_CaretY
```

Comment: Actually this question is not about Outlook. It is about AutoHotkey software.

Comment: That above command works in many programs. It doesn't in Outlook. So I would say that this is a question related to AHK and Outlook.